# downloading a zip file

Tags: php, download

While downloading a zip file through code (php), its showing all ascii characters in the browser:

```
zip successfulPKZAq>.…u[ü¹…¿;../papa/control/other_image/2965Golf Cart Pencil Holder.jpg¤ýwTSOø7ŠÆŠ€ˆ EAˆJi*UZT¤—Q©!"-@HéUA@@@¤I”€ÔH$”  %PB€$\¾ï=ëÜµîzÏZçüN²æ¯ìì½Ÿ™g>eföìÃß‡ó€ó†zz€cÇ€cG_À! ©c®{ÏÒÔ\ýŠ»‹œçW÷+·äo^¹àõq¿b`¨Åð±®þ•@•ÛÒ²W|ž>‡ú_ÑºrëæMŽÃi€ÎÑ¹þß}þ;É±ÿ×'ùà9sÌõ˜Ç‰c×ÇyŽà9vØEyêÿ{àÿø;~âä©ÓlgØ98Àœ?vâÄñ“'N:yòè×°£ß'y.......
```

This is a part of the output ..and images are being downloaded, can you help?

Comment: It looks like the server is sending a wrong content-type for the resource. Right click on the link and click "download" to get it.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're displaying "zip successful" - probably in some code where you generate the zip, the browser will not be able to handle the file (it will be corrupt anyway, regardless of using the application/zip header). So first clean up your code, and make sure you don't output anything to the browser before you start sending the ZIP over. Then add the following to actually push the zip to the client :

```
header('Content-type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($fullPathToFile) . '"')
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fullPathToFile));
header('Cache-Control: private');
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($fullPathToFile);
exit;
```

Where $fullPathToFile is the full path to the zip file (ie. /path/to/yourzip.zip).

Refer to the [readfile](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) documentation for another example.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be that the server is returning an incorrect content type in the [response header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).  If the server is telling the browser that the content is text, the browser will try to display it as text.  In the PHP code when serving the file, try adding something like this:

```
header('Content-type: application/zip');
```

Keep in mind that when transferring data over HTTP there is absolutely no concept of a "file."  There is a request and a response, each containing a header and data.  The client (browser) may choose to use the local system's API to save data as a file, and may even suggest a name for the file.  But what it's receiving isn't a "file."  In this case, the response header is incorrect for the data it's sending.

Comment: Nah, he's also displaying "zip succesful" somewhere in his code, so even if you get to push the current content to the browser, it will be corrupt.

Comment: @wimvds: Ah, good catch.  Ya, his output stream isn't clean when sending the zip.  He's just appending it to the current output.